# Matplotlib Radial Graph (polar plot) - sub axis control

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a polygon radial graph, however I cannot figure out how to make the y-tick lines polygon like the rest of the graph.

`radar.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection

def _radar_factory(num_vars):
    theta = 2*np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1-1./num_vars, num_vars)
    theta += np.pi/2

    def unit_poly_verts(theta):
        x0, y0, r = [0.5] * 3
        verts = [(r*np.cos(t) + x0, r*np.sin(t) + y0) for t in theta]
        return verts

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):
        name = 'radar'
        RESOLUTION = 1

        def fill(self, *args, **kwargs):
            closed = kwargs.pop('closed', True)
            return super(RadarAxes, self).fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            lines = super(RadarAxes, self).plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
                y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(theta * 180/np.pi, labels)

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            verts = unit_poly_verts(theta)
            return plt.Polygon(verts, closed=True, edgecolor='k')

        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            spine_type = 'circle'
            verts = unit_poly_verts(theta)
            verts.append(verts[0])
            path = Path(verts)
            spine = Spine(self, spine_type, path)
            spine.set_transform(self.transAxes)
            return {'polar': spine}

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta

def radar_graph(labels = [], values = []):
    N = len(labels) 
    theta = _radar_factory(N)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='radar')
    ax.set_ylim(0,100)
    ax.set_yticks([20, 40, 60, 80, 100])
    ax.set_yticklabels(['','','','',''])
    ax.plot(theta, values, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=.2)
    ax.fill(theta, values, color='#23B5BA')
    ax.set_varlabels(labels)

    plt.savefig("radar.png", dpi=100)
```

Here is how I call to radar.py to generate the graph:

```
from radar import radar_graph

labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
values = [65, 66, 53, 54, 78]

radar_graph(labels, values)
```

As you can see in this image the y-axis are circles but the overall structure is a polygon.Radar Image:

[image: Radar Image]

Maybe there is a way to transform the yticks similar to the spines.

Comment: A quick and easy hack would be not to use the axes grid, but simply draw the grid as line plots with gray color and dashed linestyle.

Comment: Thank you ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I agree its not the elegant solution I hoped for but it was pretty easy to accomplish.   I added the code in case anyone searching wants to know how to add that.

Comment: Well, you are not meant to provide an answer in your question. Instead you may answer your own question down in the answer field. This way the question will have an answer which can later be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Solution thought of by ImportanceOfBeingErnest, instead of trying to change the default circle sub-grid we just hide it and plot the sub-grid we want as polygon's.

We can add the following to Radar.py

```
    #Hide Circle Grid
    ax.grid(alpha=0.0)
    #Draw Sub-axis Grid
    ax.plot(theta, [.5,.5,.5,.5,.5], color='grey', linestyle='solid', linewidth=.2, alpha=1)
    ax.plot(theta, [20,20,20,20,20], color='grey', linestyle='solid', linewidth=.2, alpha=1)
    ax.plot(theta, [40,40,40,40,40], color='grey', linestyle='solid', linewidth=.2, alpha=1)
    ax.plot(theta, [60,60,60,60,60], color='grey', linestyle='solid', linewidth=.2, alpha=1)
    ax.plot(theta, [80,80,80,80,80], color='grey', linestyle='solid', linewidth=.2, alpha=1)
```

While I am sure there is a more elegant solution, this works.